# Implicit array sizing and crash c++

Tags: c++

I tried to declare and initialize the array like this int a[]={},but the program crashed.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void test(int b []){
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
    b[i]=i+1;
}

int main()
{
    int a[]={};
    test(a);
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
    cout<<a[i]<<endl;
}
```

The output on the console before it crashed is as follow:

0
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

But the program does what it suppose to be when I declared the array with size(int a[9]={}).Can someone tell me what's the reason behind?Thank you.

Comment: Undefined behavior. There's no such thing like _implicit array sizing_, you're chasing for unicorns.

Comment: Whats the size supposed to be if you don't tell c++ which size you want?

Comment: You're accessing and writing to 10 locations of an empty array. What did you expect?

Comment: I'm curious why `int a[] = {}:` is valid C++, and what happens to `a` - is it `NULL` or is it pointing to valid but not-to-be-used memory, or is it left in an uninitialised state; perhaps I should post this as a question.

Comment: @KenY-N [There are compiler errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bae4f2689ca4c94b)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I see; it's not valid C++; I shouldn't have up-voted this...

Comment: @KenY-N Ah, you did that. I already wondered _which idiot ..._ :P The correct reaction is to close the question for _simple typo_ / _no repro_ IMO.

Comment: It's still not an unreasonable question.  They tried something out, did some experiments with their compiler, and asked to have the result explained.  More research might have been in order, but it's at least not a _bad_ question.

Comment: @paddy I'm more concerned about which compiler was used by the OP, that accepted the code and left it for UB implementation.

Comment: Well, I just tried it with clang on my Mac and it didn't complain at all.  Adding `-pedantic` switch raised the correct error.  Same behaviour with g++ 5.4.0 in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

This code is ill-formed. See C++14 [dcl.init]/4:

> An empty initializer list `{}` shall not be used as the initializer-clause for an array of unknown bound.

The compiler could reject the code, and if it doesn't then the behaviour of the program is completely undefined by the C++ standard.  Some compilers have a non-standard extension allowing zero-sized arrays.

Comment: The program compiles without error in Clang 703.0.31 on my Mac and g++ 5.4.0 on my Ubuntu server.  In both cases, adding the `-pedantic` switch will raise the correct compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to use dynamic allocation?
This means you declare an array but don't give it a fixed size.

```
int size = 10;
int * arr = new int[size];
```

Now you can add things to arr[] like normal. If you need more space, you have to make another array of the new size, copy the values over, set the new array equal to the old one (arr = newArr), then IMPORTANT: do delete [] newArr;

This is because arrays do not handle memory allocation by themselves like vectors do. You have to give it a number for the size, or declare it dynamically.